# Calculate the volume of the region in the first octant bound by $y=0$, $y=x$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I am trying to calculate the volume of the region in the first octant bound by the surfaces

$$y=0,\hspace{1em}y=x,\hspace{1em}x^2+y^2+z^2=4$$

I have found that $x,\ y,$ and $z$ can have a lower bound of $0$.

$z$ seems to have an upper bound of $\sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}$

$y$ seems to be from $0$ to $x$

$x$ seems to be form $0$ to $2$ (the radius of the sphere)

Is it correct to use the following triple integral to solve the problem?

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^x \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} dz\ dy\ dx$$

Sketch:

It seems to me that the region to find is the area shown below (the left half of the section of the sphere in the first octant). It is clear to me that the volume should be that of the sphere divided by 16, but I need to learn how to use triple integrals to solve this problem.

[image]

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: I would draw a picture, first and foremost (maybe you don't even need integration). Also, are you familiar with integration in other coordinate systems than Cartesian?

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, I'm familiar with polar, cyllindrical, spherical, but I find it difficult to switch. I assume you would use spherical coordinates for this?

Comment: The fact that the boundaries are given by constants in spherical coordinates makes that an obvious candidate, yes. A drawing still helps, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the base of the solid is a sector of a circle, it is most natural to use either cylindrical or spherical coordinates. I don't know if you're in the American coordinate system or non-American, but notice that limiting $y$ to $0\le y\le x$ means that $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$ (with $\theta$ the polar coordinate in the plane). So you will have $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$, $0\le\phi\le\pi/2$ (because you're constrained to the first octant), and, easiest, $0\le\rho\le 2$. So the volume integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^2 \rho^2\sin\phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta.$$
[Interchange $\theta$ and $\phi$ as required.]

Comment: No, it is not perfectly fine. See my answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course @TonyK. The region in the $xy$-plane is the quarter-circle. Shows what happens when I've retired and am not paying attention to students' errors. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems much simpler this way and I now understand it.

Comment: @DenverCoder1 there is no doubt in that this is simpler. But I still think you need to learn how to set it up in all coordinates. For example the mistake you made is something you will have to practice and it does help in long run. I am sure Ted Shifrin would advise the same.

Comment: @MathLover I know, I've spent the past ~15 minutes working on your answer to make sure I understand how it works also. Thanks for your help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your limits are invalid. The problem is that the region defined by $(0\le x\le 2$ and $0\le y\le x)$ contains points for which $\sqrt{4-x^2-z^2}$, the upper limit for $z$, is not a real number. For instance, $(x,y)=(\frac32,\frac32)$.

It really is worth it to transform the problem into spherical coordinates!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your integral is incorrectly set up. If you are integrating in the order $dz$ first, then $dy$ and then $dx$, you will have to split your integral into two. So I would recommend going $dx$ before $dy$.

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \int_y^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} dz \ dx \ dy$.

The upper limit of $y$ comes from intersection of plane $y = x$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4$ at $z = 0$. Then $2y^2 = 4 \implies y = \sqrt2$.

Comment: Thanks for your response as well! (Sorry for the long comment with mostly just my thoughts from the past ~20 minutes) Before seeing this, I had a difficult time using variables in integral limits. Now I see why $\sqrt{4-y^2}$ makes sense since $z=0$ gives $x^2+y^2=4$. It took me a while to figure out that the outermost part of the sphere is at $\sqrt{2}$, but I can now see how you used $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ again with $x^2$ becoming $y^2$. So since we know the point we are looking for has $z=0$, we have $2y^2=4$ which will tell us the y limit. Hopefully, I can now apply it correctly in other places!

Comment: Yes. Also, as it is easier to see limits of $z$, we are more interested in what is happening in $XY$ plane and hence drawing a rough sketch of the situation in $XY$ plane would help see thing better.